# Trying to download an Image from a URL in Firebase Database. The image load time is VERY slow, why would this be?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I have an application where I am trying to download an image form the Firebase database using the url. It works, it is just very very slow. Is there any reason for this?

I have tried setting up caching but I am not sure I am doing it correctly. I am fairly new to swift and xcode.

```
//Gets the image from the database URL
func getData(from url: URL, completion: @escaping (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> ()) {
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: completion).resume()
}

func downloadImage(from url: URL) {
    getData(from: url) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }
        print(response?.suggestedFilename ?? url.lastPathComponent)
        DispatchQueue.main.async() {
            let imageToCache = UIImage(data: data)
            self.imageCache.setObject(imageToCache!, forKey: url as AnyObject)
            self.profileImageView.image = imageToCache
            //self.profileImageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
        }
    }
}
```

This is where I call the downloadImage func in the viewDidLoad() func:

```
let profileImageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("users").child(uid!).child("\(uid!)-profileImage.jpg")
    //let databaseRef = Database.database().reference().child("userProfile").child(uid!)


    profileImageRef.downloadURL { url, error in
        if let error = error {
            //handle errors
            print(error)
        } else {
            //get download URL
            if let downloadUrl = url {
                let downloadString = downloadUrl.absoluteString
                //add downloadString to the database in profileImageURL
                let url = URL(string: downloadString)!
                if let imageFromCache = self.imageCache.object(forKey: url as AnyObject) as? UIImage {
                    self.profileImageView.image = imageFromCache
                    return
                } else {
                    self.downloadImage(from: url)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is nothing in this code that explains speed or slowness of the image download. The main factor is usually the connection of the device on which you get, mostly the time it takes to roundtrip to the storage servers, and the bandwidth that it has available. You might want to see how long each step in your code takes (e.g. getting the download url vs getting the actual file contents), and see how that relates to your device's bandwidth and latency.

Comment: The problem i, I tried it on a simulator and it works pretty fast (loads the image in about 1.5 seconds) but then when I put it on my phone for testing it takes way longer (about 6 seconds). Would this be because of my phones internet speed? Is there anyway I can speed up the load time using the code?

Comment: The only thing you can consider is not calling `profileImageRef.downloadURL` when you need the image, but instead store the download URL in the database when you **upload** the image. But to determine whether that's worth the effort, you should first determine where the times goes.

Comment: ah okay cool, thank you so much for your response!

Comment: Try putting your actual device on the same wireless network as your development machine and see if that makes any difference. You may want to turn off cellular on your phone to ensure it's pulling data through wifi.